# Its not applicable for the arguments (int, String), but i have the correct format for it

Tags: java

I am just making a random class so that i can mess around and learn java with it. Ive kinda got this concept of arguments down.

```
public class OffensiveLine {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] blocks = {"Swim Move", "Hello"};
        LineMan jeff = new LineMan(80, 90);
        int i = 1;

        WideReciever.block(32, blocks[i]);
        jeff.block();
    }

}

public class WideReciever extends Speed{
    static Date now = new Date(1);

    public WideReciever() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
    }

    public static void run(){

    }

    public static void block(int b, String[] wow){
        int i = 1;
        System.out.println(wow[i]);


    }

}
```

Comment: `blocks[i]` is a String not a String array.

Comment: I like your variable name.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void block(int b, String[] wow){
```

This method wants a String array.

However, you call it like this:

```
WideReciever.block(32, blocks[i]);
```

`blocks` is a String array, but `blocks[i]` is just a string.

You could either change the `block` method to take a string, or pass the array in:

```
public static void block(int b, String[] wow) {
    System.out.println(wow[1]);
}
```

or:

```
WideReciever.block(32, blocks);
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
    WideReciever.block(32, blocks[i]);
```

Is passing in an `int` and a `String` to a method which accepts an `int` and a String array. What you are likely trying to do is:

```
    WideReciever.block(32, blocks);
```